# MySQL NDB Management Node Got Different Node IP Address Against the config.ini

Tags: mysql, cluster

I am engaging with a MySQL HA configuration. Currently, I setup the config.ini on my management node:

```
root@ndb-mgmd:~# cat config.ini |grep -v ^#

[tcp default] 
SendBufferMemory=2M 
ReceiveBufferMemory=2M

[ndb_mgmd default] 
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster


[ndb_mgmd] 
HostName=ndb-mgmd


[ndbd default] 

NoOfReplicas=2


LockPagesInMainMemory=1


DataMemory=100M 
IndexMemory=50M

NoOfFragmentLogFiles=300 
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster 
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=1000

SchedulerSpinTimer=400 
SchedulerExecutionTimer=100 
RealTimeScheduler=1

TimeBetweenGlobalCheckpoints=1000 
TimeBetweenEpochs=200 RedoBuffer=32M

MaxNoOfTables=1024 
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=256

[ndbd] 
HostName=192.168.0.20

[ndbd] 
HostName=192.168.0.21
```

After I started ndb_mgmd, the ip of the nodes shows differently:

```
root@ndb-mgmd:~# ndb_mgmd --config-file=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3
root@ndb-mgmd:~# ndb_mgm
-- NDB Cluster -- Management Client --
ndb_mgm> show
Connected to Management Server at: localhost:1186
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.21)
id=3 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.22)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @192.168.0.30  (mysql-5.7.18 ndb-7.6.3)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.21)
id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from 192.168.0.22)
```

Where does the "192.168.0.22" come from?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out. The "--config-dir" should also be used in ndb_mgmd cmdlet. So, the full string is

> ndb_mgmd --config-dir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster --config-file=/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini